# Не извлекается элемент списка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, list, bs4

при сохранении результатов в json единственный элемент списка, переменной amount отображается в квадратных скобках, во так:   "amount": "['130']", вместо: "130"

Вот мой код:

```
name = soup.select_one('.ad-detail-title').text.strip()
amount = soup.select_one('.pagAnuPrecioTexto')
about = soup.select_one('.pagAnuCuerpoAnu')
ref = soup.select_one('.pillDiv pillRef')
location = soup.select_one('.pagAnuCatLoc').text.strip()
created = soup.select_one('.pagAnuStatsCreated').text.strip()

amount = regex.findall('(\d+)', str(amount))

item = {
    'name': name,
    'amount': str(amount),
    'about': about,
    'ref': str(ref),
    'location': str(location),
    'created': str(created),
    'url': url,
}
data.append(item)

return data
```

При попытке указания позиции в списке [0] возвращается ошибка: "list index out of range python" В чём тут дело?

Comment: А может у вас там не всегда есть что-то. Может бывает, что `regex.findall` пустой список возвращает, надо проверять этот случай прежде чем брать элемент `[0]` от списка.

Comment: Куда конкретно вы выбор по индексу 0 добавляете?

Comment: вот сюда: 'amount': str(amount[0]),

Comment: `amount = soup.select_one('.pagAnuPrecioTexto')` и `'amount': str(amount),` где тут json? :) Вы туда строковое представление `bs4.Tag` помещаете. В вашем случае сразу разобраться с значением в `amount` и если там квадратные скобки, то убрать их. А так, непонятно в каком месте ошибки, ведь в `amount` у вас строка, а не список, поэтому с тем значением такой ошибки не будет, даже если там будет пустая строка (у пустых строк такая ошибка будет: `IndexError: string index out of range`)

Comment: `вот сюда: 'amount': str(amount[0]),` у вас там точно выше не `select`? Для `select_one` код бы другую ошибку выдал, что-то вроде `KeyError: 0`

Comment: Вообще, давайте не будем гадать по вашим ошибкам :) Дайте ссылку на страницу и минимальный код для воспроизведения ошибки с ожидаемым результатом

Comment: @gil9red Там в середине кода ещё строка `amount = regex.findall('(\d+)', str(amount))`, если вы не заметили ;)  Вообще западло, конечно, в одну переменную по очереди разные сущности писать. Очень запутывает ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, действительно не заметил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `amount` ниже будет список строк, найденных в `amount`:

```
amount = regex.findall('(\d+)', str(amount))

item = {
    'name': name,
    'amount': str(amount),
    ...
```

И при вашей попытке оставить первое значение из списка через `str(amount[0])` привело к ошибке, т.к. встретилось значение `amount`, в котором цифр не было, поэтому вам нужно добавить проверку, например:

```
...
item = {
    'name': name,
    'amount': amount[0] if amount else "0",
    ...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё сработало!

Comment: @AlexKurs, пожалуйста :)